# Setting axis values of a 2D contour plot without using xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to set the values of the x and y-axes of a plot generated using contour() but am currently unable to read specific values off of the axes as desried.

```
fid_list = []
for fidN in arange(frames):
    offset = fidN * fid_pts 
    current_fid = cmplx_data[offset:offset+fid_pts]
    fid_list.append(current_fid)

fid_mat = fid_list
jres_spec = abs(fftshift(fft2(fid_mat)))
max_val = jres_spec.max()/15
min_val = max_val*0.15
steps = 40
figure()
CS=contour(jres_spec,arange(min_val,max_val,(max_val-min_val)/steps))
show()
```

Which generates a plot like this

[image]
Previously I've been using xticks and yticks to set the values of the axes, but now the exact position on the plot has become important, so being able to read values off the axes would be very helpful which I can't doing with x/yticks.

When plotting a 1D spectrum, I use the following formula to enable me to read off the x-axis

```
bins = arange(828, -196, -1) #change this so that 0 value occurs at value it's meant to
x = (2000 * bins / 1024.0)/128.0
plot(x, fftshift(fft(fid_list[0])))
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
show()
```

And would similarly use this for the y-axis of my 2D contour plot

```
ybins = arange(15, -15, -1)
y = ybins * ((1/(15*10^(-3)))/ 30.0)
```

But I'm having trouble integrating this into my code...

I've tried using something like this

```
ybins = arange(15, -15, -1)
y = ybins * ((1/(15*10^(-3)))/ 30.0)
xbins = arange(828, -196, -1) 
x = (2000 * xbins / 1024.0)/128.0

fid_mat = fid_list
jres_spec = abs(fftshift(fft2(fid_mat)))
max_val = jres_spec.max()/15
min_val = max_val*0.15
steps = 40
figure()
CS=contour((x, y, jres_spec),arange(min_val,max_val,(max_val-min_val)/steps))
show()
```

which returned

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dominicc/<ipython-input-34-28b34c6c069d> in <module>()
      7 bins = arange(828, -196, -1) #change this so that 0 value occurs at value it's meant to
      8 x = (2000 * bins / 1024.0)/128.0
----> 9 CS=contour((x_list, jres_spec),arange(min_val,max_val,(max_val-min_val)/steps))
     10 show()

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in contour(*args, **kwargs)
   2195         ax.hold(hold)
   2196     try:
-> 2197         ret = ax.contour(*args, **kwargs)
   2198         draw_if_interactive()
   2199     finally:

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.pyc in contour(self, *args, **kwargs)
   7379         if not self._hold: self.cla()
   7380         kwargs['filled'] = False
-> 7381         return mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
   7382     contour.__doc__ = mcontour.QuadContourSet.contour_doc
   7383 

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.pyc in __init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1110         are described in QuadContourSet.contour_doc.
   1111         """
-> 1112         ContourSet.__init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1113 
   1114     def _process_args(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.pyc in __init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
    701         if self.origin == 'image': self.origin = mpl.rcParams['image.origin']
    702 
--> 703         self._process_args(*args, **kwargs)
    704         self._process_levels()
    705 

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.pyc in _process_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1123             self.zmax = args[0].zmax
   1124         else:
-> 1125             x, y, z = self._contour_args(args, kwargs)
   1126 
   1127             x0 = ma.minimum(x)

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.pyc in _contour_args(self, args, kwargs)
   1167         if Nargs <= 2:
   1168             z = ma.asarray(args[0], dtype=np.float64)
-> 1169             x, y = self._initialize_x_y(z)
   1170             args = args[1:]
   1171         elif Nargs <=4:

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.pyc in _initialize_x_y(self, z)
   1230         '''
   1231         if z.ndim != 2:
-> 1232             raise TypeError("Input must be a 2D array.")
   1233         else:
   1234             Ny, Nx = z.shape

TypeError: Input must be a 2D array.
```

And I'm now struggling to think of other ways I could do this.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the error by taking out the extra parenthesis in the call to `contour`:

```
CS=contour(x, y, jres_spec,arange(min_val,max_val,(max_val-min_val)/steps))
```

If that doesn't give you the plot you want, try `xlim` and `ylim` to set the axis limits directly.